# Correctly iterating through json array

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to parse through an json array and get the values from it but facing some issues.

I have my json that I get as:

```
[{
    "ID1":"1",
    "ID2":"2",
    "ID3":"3",
    "ID4":"4"
},
{
    "ID1":"5",
    "ID2":"6",
    "ID3":"7",
    "ID4":"8"
}]
```

The key ID1, ID2 etc are not fixed. For ex I can also have my json as:

```
[{
    "ID1":"1",
    "ID2":"2"
},
{
    "ID1":"5",
    "ID2":"6"
}]
```

Or there can be more keys also, ie its dynamic so I cant create a model and map my json to it.

I was trying to deserialize that and get the data by using the following code.:

```
public IActionResult GetData(string data)
{
    //here data is my json
    List<string> myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(data);
    foreach (string s in myList)
    {
        //get values here
    }
    return Json("");
}
```

But above gives me error when deserializing as:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while >parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 2.'

So I wanted to know how what is the correct method to loop through this json and get key values from it.

Comment: You dont have a list of string, you have a list of _object_.  Since your keys are not fixes you can just use a `Dictionary<string, string>` as your object

Comment: @maccettura I tried to use this:  Dictionary<string, string> conditionsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data); Is this how you are talking about? It gives me error:  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: No, I told you that your JSON is a _list_ of `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is a list of *object*, your issue is that you are trying to deserialize into a list of *string*.  This will not work for obvious reasons.

Instead you want to deserialize into a list of objects, and since your objects keys change the best thing you can use is a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(data);
```

Keep in mind that the JSON you posted is a `Dictionary<string, string>` but as soon as you get integers or bools in that JSON you should change to `Dictionary<string, object>`

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kv3XzP)

Comment: Thanks I understood what was missing now.